# How do you create GUIs in Java?

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, methods

I'm using Java and I have been always looking for ways to make my program and upload it online but I don't know how to put my code in a graphical user interface. I want to package it all together so that users can just click on an icon to run it without having to compile.

How do I create graphical user interfaces for Java programs and distribute those programs online?

Answer (score 5):

Learn Java Swing
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Learn about Java Webstart
http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml

Use Netbeans for creating your GUI (or another IDE)
http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

Answer (score 4):

It depends as there are several ways to create GUIs in Java.

1. Desktop GUI (e.g. Swing, AWT)
2. Web GUI (e.g. JSF / JSP)
3. Mobile GUI (e.g. Android, Java ME)

The jar file alone can be distributed. If you mean creating an exe out of a jar, take a look at [Jar2Exe](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/)